# Getting data from nested JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I've got an object like so...

```
var oInfoModal = "{"modals":[{"myID":17,"warningIdx":[0]},{"myID":12,"warningIdx":[1,2]},{"myID":11,"warningIdx":[3]},{"myID":10,"warningIdx":[4]},{"myID":9,"warningIdx":[5,6,7]},{"myID":8,"warningIdx":[8]},{"myID":7,"warningIdx":[9,10]},{"myID":6,"warningIdx":[11,12]},{"myID":5,"warningIdx":[13,14]},{"myID":4,"warningIdx":[15,16]},{"myID":3,"warningIdx":[17]},{"myID":1,"warningIdx":[18,19]},{"myID":0,"warningIdx":[20,21]}]}";
```

I'd like to filter the object based on a warnIdx value passed to a function but I'm getting empty object as the result. I know the issue is with oInfoModal.modals.warningIdx being an array, itself. But I'm not sure how to return the filtered oInfoModal.modals object.

```
function filterInfoModals(warnIdx) {
  return oInfoModal.modals.filter(function (item) {
    return item.warningIdx == warnIdx;
  });
}
```

I've also tried

```
function filterInfoModals(warnIdx) {
    return oInfoModal.modals.filter(function (item) {
        return item.warningIdx.filter(function (idx,val) {
            return val.warningIdx == warnIdx;
        });
    });
}
```

Which gives me back the original, unfiltered, object.

Just going in circles now. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `return item.warningIdx.indexOf(warnIdx) > -1` for your first example?

Comment: That did the trick. function filterInfoModals(warnIdx) {
  return oInfoModal.modals.filter(function (item) {
 return item.warningIdx.indexOf(warnIdx) > -1;
  });
}

Comment: Also, are you setting that oInfoModal to that 'string' in your code? It needs to be wrapped in single quotes if you are using double quotes to indicate fields and values... and, if oInfoModal is a string, you need to JSON.parse() it into an actual object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a valid object. You have it wrapped in " " quotes, so therefore it is a string. Thus, your filter is not going to work properly. There are other syntax errors in your object as well that are going to prevent it from working properly. Here is the complete fix:

```
var oInfoModal = {
  "modals": [
    { "myID": 17, "warningIdx": [0] },
    { "myID": 12, "warningIdx": [1, 2] },
    { "myID": 11, "warningIdx": [3] },
    { "myID": 10, "warningIdx": [4] },
    { "myID": 9, "warningIdx": [5, 6, 7] },
    { "myID": 8, "warningIdx": [8] },
    { "myID": 7, "warningIdx": [9, 10] },
    { "myID": 6, "warningIdx": [11, 12] },
    { "myID": 5, "warningIdx": [13, 14] },
    { "myID": 4, "warningIdx": [15, 16] },
    { "myID": 3, "warningIdx": [17] },
    { "myID": 1, "warningIdx": [18, 19] },
    { "myID": 0, "warningIdx": [20, 21] }
  ]
};

function filterInfoModals(warnIdx) {
  return oInfoModal.modals.filter(function (item) {
    return item.warningIdx.indexOf(warnIdx) > -1;
  });
}
console.log(filterInfoModals(1,2));
```

Comment: apologies. It actually is generated automatically by my code. I didn't copy it properly. Thank you for you're help.

Comment: @ChrisG. See above for final solution.